# Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct

Tags: unity, android

For some reason, I am unable to test my android program because of this error.
Here are some pictures of the errors. This error is not allowing me to test my app on my test Android device, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, checking if it is acatually the root folder, everything, PLEASE HELP!

**1st error**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. 
C:/Users/jayso/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager.bat list target -c

stderr[

]
stdout[

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunAndroidSdkTool (System.String toolName, System.String arguments, Boolean updateCommand, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.ListTargetPlatforms (UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetTopAndroidPlatformAvailable (UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKPlatformDetector.GetVersion (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK+SDKComponentDetector.Detect (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools sdkTools, System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.ProgressHandler onProgress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (System.Version minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SDKComponentDetector detector)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.EnsureSDKComponentVersion (Int32 minVersion, UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.SDKComponentDetector detector)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckAndroidSDK.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

**2nd Error**

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. 
C:/Users/jayso/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager.bat list target -c

stderr[

]
stdout[

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
]
exit code: 1
```

[image: My Unity preferences]

Comment: Not to be condecending, but did you [try Google first](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+unable+to+list+platforms)? I see two answers.unity.com posts, five Stack Overflow posts, and three YouTube videos about this problem.

Comment: Yes I've been looking for about 5 hours between yesterday and today none of the soloutions have helped.

Comment: Then update your question to include what you tried and why those solutions didn't work for you. "PLEASE HELP" is not a problem description

Comment: Update or redownload Android SDK

Comment: Tried that many times

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message as code in your question, rather than posting screenshots of the error. This helps people with the same issue in the future find your question when searching.

Comment: @sonny ok as soon as possible I will change it

Comment: Try debugging why your JAVA_HOME variable is not being set. For example, see [this relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152088/5170571). (Note: I've deleted my answer related to JDK 8 because you seem to be on the correct version.)

Comment: @sonny Unity 2018.1 came out yesterday and they seem to have fixed the issue when I updated unity, Thank you.

Comment: @JaysonMeribe No problem, I'm glad your issue is fixed. I've restored my answer so you can mark this question with an accepted answer, or you can post your own answer and accept your own answer. It would be helpful if you could answer with why updating to 2018.1 fixed the issue, especially if you have any links that explain what exact issue was fixed in Unity 2018.1.

Answer (score 1):

(*EDIT: Updating to Unity 2018.1 fixed the issue for the asker. The below answer is not correct for this case, but it may be relevant for other people with the same error message*)

You need to downgrade your JDK version to JDK 8 for now.

There is an [active issue on the Unity Issue Tracker for JDK 9](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-builds-fail-with-java-9-jdk-and-unable-to-list-target-platforms-error).

If this does not solve your issue, you should debug to see if your JAVA_HOME path is set correctly in your PATH variable as your error message suggests.  For more details, see [this relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152088/5170571).

Comment: I checked and I actually have JDK version 1.8 in my Unity preferences. There is a picture I posted on the question showing my preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to unity 2018.1 solved the issue